# Delegate always getting nil value in dynamic framework class

Tags: ios, swift, dynamic, sdk, delegates

I used delegation for passing data to ViewController B to A in dynamic framework . B is my dynamic framework ViewController . A is my app ViewController . I am always set delegate as self in my A class 
Without dynamic framework it works perfectly

Class B code : Inside dynamic framework (Using .xib)

```
import UIKit
public protocol MediaDataDelegate: class{
       func mediaDidFinish(controller: 
       LoginViewController,transactionId:String,returnURL: String)
}

public class LoginViewController: UIViewController {
public var message = ""
public var delegate: MediaDataDelegate?
public init() {
    super.init(nibName: "LoginViewController", bundle: Bundle(for: LoginViewController.self))
    print("message 1234 :\(message)")
}
required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
override open func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print("message 1234 :\(message)")
}
public class func logToConsole(_ msg: String) {
    print(msg);
}

@IBAction func backToMainBtnTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

    self.delegate?.mediaDidFinish(controller: self, transactionId: "WERTYQWRCT", returnURL: "www.media.com")
}
}
```

Class A Code:Inside Other App (Using Storyboard)

Click on conduct IPVButton navigate to dynamic framework view controller 
I also pass some value to message string but in dynamic framework class getting empty string.

```
import UIKit
import NBView
class ViewController: UIViewController ,MediaDataDelegate{

var loginVC = LoginViewController()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    LoginViewController.logToConsole("hello media")
}

@IBAction func conductIPVBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    loginVC.delegate = self
    present(loginVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
func mediaDidFinish(controller: LoginViewController, transactionId: 
String, returnURL: String) {
    print("Trans Id\(transactionId)")
    print("return URl \(returnURL)")
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are instantiating incorrectly the `LoginViewController`

You need to do it this way, since you wrote that you have it in a `.xib` file:

`let loginVC = LoginViewController(nibName: yourNibName, bundle: nil)`

Always have a `weak` reference to your `delegate`, otherwise you will have a retain cycle:

`weak var delegate: MediaDataDelegate?`

Also, you don't need to use `public` everywhere where you thought it might fit. Use it wisely and when needed. Here you don't need it. Remove it from everywhere in your `LoginViewController`

Comment: Fixed it by instead of passing .self                                                           loginVC.delegate = ViewController()
Thanks for response.

Comment: You are welcome! Would be nice if you would also select as the correct answer :)

Comment: Is there any reference link or documentation available for proper way of building dynamic libraries with advance level? Your suggestion will be appreciated.@Starsky

Comment: I don't have much experience with that, but a Google Search for "dynamic library swift" might help you.

Comment: Ok.Very less resource available. Thats fine. You are right . I should be use access specifier wisely and delegate property use as weak reference.